# Преобразование wav файла для БПФ

Tags: c#, wav, fft

Читается wav файл (16-бит) в битовый массив buffer, далее стоит задача преобразовать данный массив для "Быстрого Преобразования Фурье". Для этого использую представленный ниже алгоритм:

```
public static double[] readAmplitudeValues(byte[] buffer, bool isBigEndian = true)
    {
        int MSB, LSB; // старший и младший байты
        double[] data = new double[buffer.Length / 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            if (isBigEndian) // задает порядок байтов во входном сигнале
            {
                // первым байтом будет MSB
                MSB = buffer[2 * i];
                // вторым байтом будет LSB
                LSB = buffer[2 * i + 1];
            }
            else
            {
                // наоборот
                LSB = buffer[2 * i];
                MSB = buffer[2 * i + 1];
            }
            // склеиваем два байта, чтобы получить 16-битное вещественное число
            // все значения делятся на максимально возможное - 2^15
            data[i] = ((MSB << 8) | LSB) / 32768.0;
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Как понять рабочий ли алгоритм (на выходе в массиве data нет отрицательных значений)? И какой шаг нужно сделать дальше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отрицательных чисел нет, поскольку знаковый бит 32-разрядного числа не заполняется при операции `MSB << 8`

Следует использовать тип `short` для знаковых 16-разрядных чисел. [IDeone](https://ideone.com/msRYO3)

```
public static void Main()
{
    byte b = 0x80;
    short MSB;
    short LSB;
    double data;
    MSB = b;
    LSB = b;
    data = (((short)(MSB << 8)) | LSB) / 32768.0;
    Console.Out.WriteLine(data);
}

>>-0.99609375
```